# Cómo puedo separar los registros de una lista en dos DataGridViews

Tags: c#, mvvm, datagrid

Que tal, estoy trabajando con MVVM y tengo una lista con 64 registros que se llena con información del DataLayer, lo que quiero hacer es poner los primeros 32 registros de esa lista en un DataGrid y los otros 32 en otro DataGrid, ambos DGV se encuentran en el mismo UserControl, por lo que están usando el mismo ViewModel, espero que me puedan ayudar. 
Saludos

Comment: vas a tener dos sources? mas alla del modelo, cada uno va a recibir los registros de que forma?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema. Separa los datos en 2 `ObservableCollection` por ejemplo y pon cada uno como binding de cada `DataGrid`

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que el resultado de tu DataLayer es una lista de 64 elementos:

```
var lista1 = DataLayerResult.Take(32);
var lista2 = DataLayerResult.Skip(32).Take(32);
```